# How to declare functions in Realm classes?

Tags: javascript, realm

Looking [at the documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/), Realm objects can support functions in realm classes like so

```
class Person extends Realm.Object {
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

However, I need to have a function that is appended to the realm object (as all objects of this schema will need this). I can't find much documentation on the `get` operator and guessing from it's name, I'm assuming it requires me to return something. I could return null but that's messy. How can I declare a function like so

```
class Person extends Realm.Object {
   function doTheThing(thatThing) {
        ThingsToDo.DoThis(thatThing);
      }
   }
```

Without returning anything?

**EDIT:** I was attempting to do what I needed within the get function, however it looks like this is how Realm's collection evaluates get functions

```
if (isIndex(property)) {
            return getProperty(collection[keys.realm], collection[keys.id], property);
}
```

And it seems to not run the code in the get function unless it's in a return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` defines a class property getter which is not the same as a traditional object method. [See the docs for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Since class support is still considered "limited" (per the Realm documentation), the problem you're having is probably "by design" and at this time only getters are supported. You'll likely need to move your logic into a utility method that you can pass your Realm model instances through.